# Cloth Simulation Breaks

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I have trouble using cloth simulation and rigidbody. I attached a string to a pumpkin (which is the rigidbody part), and I set the string to have a cloth physics property. However, when I start the simulation, the string just breaks without reason. Please help me solve this problem.

Link to file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CL1vz-TE52nkvyK6aDs268PHjIFtQ96R?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you should fake the simulation? what is your final goal?

Comment: I don't want the string to break. I just want the string to be hang on the character's neck. And I haven't heard of faking simulations before, what is it?

Comment: First off maybe you should pin the top of the rope and parent to the body so that it stick to the neck?

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple pin groups pinned? I'm already pinning the bottom part of the string on the pumpkin.

Comment: Why do you even use a physic simulation to begin with? This doesn't look like a scenario that asks for it. A bunch of bones would do it in a simpler way.

Comment: Yeah thats true, but I'm still wondering why the string breaks.

Comment: because the physic simulations are not completely accurate   ;)   you often need to cheat, and if you can do without physics, do it

Comment: got it, thank you!